# Запустить PHPUnit тесты из docker контейнера через PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, composer, docker, phpunit

### Что есть:

- Docker-контейнер с PHP и набором юнит-тестов. Можно запустить контейнер, и внутри через консоль запускать любые тесты - `phpunit /test/test_1.php`
- хостовая машина с установленным PhpStorm 9
- папка с проектом, где лежат в том числе юнит-тесты. Эта папка залинкована в докер-контейнер.

### Проблема:

PhpStorm удобно менеджерит тесты, и позволяет запускать локальные или удаленные тесты (посредством SSH). Но с докером работать не умеет, не получается обьяснить IDE как запускать тесты, лежащие в докере.

### Что нужно:

Как поднастроить докер или PhpStorm, чтобы через GUI можно было запускать тесты.

### Дополнения:

- по ssh работает сейчас, но хотелось бы обойтись без него.
- пробовал создать bash-скрипт, который проксирует все запросы в контейнер. Вот такой скрипт `docker run --rm php:cli php $@`. Таким образом начинает работать команда `php -v` запущенная с хостовой машины. Но тесты используют аргументы файлы. Усложнил баш-скрипт:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  args=''
  for arg
  do
     if [ -f $arg ]; then
          arg=/mnt$( realpath $arg )
     fi
     args="$args $arg"
  done
  env > /tmp/docker-env
  sed -i s/idekey=.*/idekey=PHPSTORM/ /tmp/docker-env
  docker run -e "PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=phpunit-docker" \
     --net=host --env-file /tmp/docker-env --rm \
     -v /:/mnt -v /var/www:/var/www app php $args
  ```
- Это решает несколько проблем

  - можно создать php.sh с этим кодом, и положить в любое место, например в /usr/local/bin, и обращаться с ним вроде это настоящий php
  - phpstorm вызывая тесты создает /tmp/ide-phpunit.php который принимает env переменные которые настраиваются в самой ide, поэтому я использую /tmp/docker-env
  - настройка --net=host решает все проблемы с сетью, например nslookup раньше выпадал с ошибкой
- Это не решает проблемы

  - явного указания idekey=PHPSTORM и PHP_IDE_CONFIG
- Но всё равно PHPUnit тесты не запускаются, ругается composer

  > PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare    composerRequire7a368ac394ae1d2e857becf2a235ebaa() (previously declared in    [APP_ROOT]/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:56) in    [APP_ROOT]/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59

  Я подозреваю что это происходит потому что /tmp/ide-phpunit.php вызывает composer/autoload для нахождения phpunit, и при запуске тесты тоже запускают этот же

Comment: Запускайте ssh-контейнер, кладите в него ваш проект, запускайте по ssh.

Comment: @Etki хм, неочень понял. Контейнер с проектов уже создан на сонове слоя php, сделать его на основе слоя ssh я не могу. Если создать новый контейнер ssh который будет ликоваться с php контейнером, то это мне непоможет, так как нету доступа к утилите phpunit. Покажите пример простенький пример. –

Comment: по моему я понял что вы имели, нужно установить open-ssh в контейнер с php, и настроить конект в phpstorm как к удаленному серверу. Если это так, добавте ваш комент в ответы

Comment: Зачем вам docker, зачем усложнять разработку на машине.

Comment: пока что все упростилось, и ускорилось в полтора раза. Вместо vagrant использую docker-compose, теперь сайт подымаеться за 10 секунд, вместо 1 часа. Теперь доустановить требуемый сервис требует 10 минут, вместо 2 дней, потому что я беру готовый образ и не думаю как установить и настроить

Answer (score 3):

В PhpStorm можно настроить запуск тестов через SSH. Ниже инструкция, как запустить SSH-сервер в debian/ubuntu контейнере (docker image `php:cli` - это debian).

Зайдите в контейнер. Допустим, он называется `phpapp`

```
docker exec -it phpapp bash
```

Устанавливаем SSH-сервер

```
apt-get update; apt-get install openssh-server
```

Запускаем SSH-сервер. Почему-то нужно указывать полный путь.

```
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

Если будет ругаться, возможно, ему нужно создать какой-то каталог перед запуском

```
mkdir /var/run/sshd
```

Добавляем пользователя

```
adduser test
```

Выходим из контейнера - <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>

Пробрасываем 22-й порт контейнера на какой-то из локальных портов, например, 127.0.0.1:10022 (вместо 10022 можно выбрать любое число 1025-65535). Если запускаете на Windows через VirtualBox/Vagrant/docker-machine, то пробрасывайте на 0.0.0.0:10022 и в VirtualBox настройте проброску локального порта 10022 на порт 10022 в вашем VirtualBox.

Логинимся в контейнер - `ssh test@127.0.0.1:10022`, где `test` - это пользователь, которого вы создали.

Устанавливать SSH в Docker считается плохим тоном, но пока в PhpStorm простая и красивая интеграция с PHPUnit (не просто консоль, а список тестов и coverage) работает только через SSH. На production так не делайте.

Comment: ssh в локальном докере не нужен, а проблема решается элементарным скриптом, который вешается на хоткей в php-storm  и делает docker exec / запуск тестов

Comment: а как стягивать информацию о coverage? также не знаю, достаточно ли PhpStorm стандартного output или он генерирует результаты в xml и потом их анализирует.

Comment: вывод тестов кладете в папки прилинкованные на хосте, например. PhpStorm вывод не генерирует, его PhpUnit генерирует. Кстати, имхо, в принципе, если не хватает консольных тестов, то лучше уже интеграцию какую-нибудь поднять.

Comment: да, но как заставить PhpStorm их подтягивать откуда нужно - там совсем мало настроек. ssh не такое уже и зло - мы же подразумеваем, что это хак для dev-окружения, которого в большинстве случаев можно избежать. юнит-тесты лучше писать так, чтобы они не зависели от OS и окружения. у меня все запускаются на локальной машине. а интеграционные можно и не из PhpStorm запускать.

Comment: да нет никакой разницы как логинится в контейнер, если ты можешь зайти в него без ссх, простым логином в докер, то лучше делать так, чем через костыль и лишнюю зависимость. Если ты можешь их через ссх подсасывать, значит и через простой логин можешь. (или я чего-то не понимаю совсем)  Кстати, не знаю, пригодится или нет, но codeception вполне клево запускается в докере используя phantomjs

Comment: я имею ввиду, что пользователи докера первым делом думают "а как зайти в докер! нужно поставить ssh-сервер!" it's a bad practice. За последние пару лет (а я столько внедрял докер в нашей разработке) ни единого случая, когда стоило использовать ssh вместо логина в контейнер - не было.

Comment: если самому запускать из командной строки, то есть куча хороших вариантов. просто вопрос был "как запускать из PhpStorm", а там немного вариантов. если подскажете как правильно запустить phpunit внутри докера именно из PhpStorm без ssh - скажите. я не знаю как.

Comment: если докер ругается на nslookup, то ccх тут не поможет - он и дальше будет ругаться, реши проблему докера.

Comment: если я сегодня-завтра успею, то ради интереса попробую.  Но, сам PhpStorm умеет запускать любые скрипты с любыми параметрами. Однажды я (до докера) со штормом и таким-то баш-скриптом комитил на дев-сервер через ssh. Автор оригинального поста, в принципе, был на правильном пути.

Comment: олсо, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510895/running-phpunit-within-a-docker-container-with-phpstorm

Comment: просто запустить команду неинтересно - он выведет то же, что и в консоли. если правильно запускать, то выводит в красивом оформлении (слева сгруппированные тесты с временем выполнения), позволяет перейти на поломанный тест; можно отфильтровать все/только поломанные, отсортировать по времени выполнения; по горячей клавише запустить только один файл или метод.

Answer (score 2):

Почему не установить phpunit на хостовую машину? зачем так переусложнять себе жизнь? Сорсы ведь на локальной машине и залинкованы внутрь докер-контейнера.Прогоняйте тесты вне докера, просто используйте аналогичную версию phpunit на хостовой машине.
Это рабочий, проверенный мной вариант.

Comment: Всецело поддерживаю. Лид/тестер ставит себе локальный сервак, тестит, после этого делает деплой.

Comment: @mkardakov гдето 5 лет назад я использовал такой способ, но после проблем несовместимости версий я больше не буду это использовать. Темболее прогонять тесты вне докера это значит развернуть на лольной машине окружение для приложения, зачем тогда мне докер. Я поддерживаю несколько версий приложения и переключаюсь между разными приложениями, если использовать ваш ответ мне придеться установить все версии phpunit, и каждый раз при запуске проверятьк какая версия мне нужна.

Comment: Нужно только установить минимальное окружение для php-cli + phar.
Зачем "все версии" устанавливать? PHPUnit 5.5 нормально будет справляться с более старыми версиями в определенном диапазоне. Или у вас приложение поддерживается от php3 до php7 ? )

Comment: unit-тесты так отлично работают, нужно только следить, чтобы была одинаковая версия PHP, потому что программа, которая работает на вашем локальном PHP 7 могут ломаться на production PHP 5.x.

Comment: тем более что контейнер - это по сути виртуализированный процесс. А вы пытаетесь сделать из него виртуальную машину. Тогда уже и phpStorm из докера можно запускать по ssh с поддержкой X сервера и всё будет работать. Только зачем?

Comment: @mkardakov по поводу установить только php-cli + phar вам уже ответил #luchaninov, а я добавлю что придеться поставить все версии php :) (выше я написал почему) c разными расширениями типа pecl или вообще вкомпиленых. Также PHPUnit 5.5 запускаться будет, но тесты проходить не будут(из за несоответсвий версий), чаще всего это проявляется в рендомных падениях, поэтому в composer.json указывают версии которые уже проверенны для конкретного приложения. По поводу того что я хочу сделать виртуальную машину, я этого не хочу и сопротивляюсь устанавливать в контейнер еще и ssh агента.